# If else statement in a spread operator

Tags: reactjs

I am quite new to React, and am having a little bit of trouble trying to add an "if" statement within a spread component:

Sample code:

```
class CalenderView extends Component {
  parseActivitiesForCalendar = (activities) => {
    return activities.map((activity) => {
      return {
        ...activity,
        id: activity.id,
        title: Dates.getTimeString(activity.startDate) +" - "+ activity.desc,
        start: Dates.getDateTimeFromUnix(activity.startDate),
        end: Dates.getDateTimeFromUnix(activity.endDate)
      }
    })
  }
```

With the "title", I am trying add the following condition:

```
if(Dates.getTimeString(activity.startDate)=="00:00") {
    title: "All Day - "+ activity.desc,
} else {
  title: Dates.getTimeString(activity.startDate) +" - "+ activity.desc,
}
```

However unsure how to write this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If else don't work in the object, you can rather make use of ternary operators to get the desired result.

```
class CalenderView extends Component {
  parseActivitiesForCalendar = (activities) => {
    return activities.map((activity) => {
      return {
        ...activity,
        id: activity.id,
        title: (Dates.getTimeString(activity.startDate)=="00:00")? "All Day - "+ activity.desc : Dates.getTimeString(activity.startDate) +" - "+ activity.desc,
        start: Dates.getDateTimeFromUnix(activity.startDate),
        end: Dates.getDateTimeFromUnix(activity.endDate)
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Write it like this by using [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
return {
    ...activity,
    id: activity.id,

    title: Dates.getTimeString(activity.startDate) == "00:00" ? "All Day - " + activity.desc : Dates.getTimeString(activity.startDate) +" - "+ activity.desc,

    start: Dates.getDateTimeFromUnix(activity.startDate),
    end: Dates.getDateTimeFromUnix(activity.endDate)
}
```

Comment: As always :) 25 sec difference

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
title: Dates.getTimeString(activity.startDate)=="00:00"? "All Day - "+ activity.desc : Dates.getTimeString(activity.startDate) +" - "+ activity.desc;
```